# Regexp - finding first word in a group of repeating words after a particular word

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I have a string `"Foo Bar Foo Bar"`, I want to select the first Bar in that string

At the moment I have:
http://regexr.com?37mv1 which is not quite right

This is the first Foo 'Bar' I ever had in Foo Bar. 'Bar' should be picked up.....Hope it makes sense

Comment: Why do you just not use the literal regex `Bar` then? And after what particular word?

Comment: What are you trying to do with first `Bar`? Also specify language/tool

Comment: Not clear at all. Please explain further. (It sounds like it can't be done with regex, though.)

Comment: of course it can be done in regex, `/(Bar)/` would return the first occurrence.  But I agree, the question is not clear at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
^.*?Foo\s*(Bar)
```

or more simple:

```
^.*?(Bar)
```

or more efficient (with long strings):

```
^(?>[^F]++|F(?!oo))*Foo\s*(Bar)
```

The problem of your pattern is the first greedy quantifier `.*`. This subpattern will match all possible character until the end of the string/line, then the regex engine must go back character by character until it find `Foo`, but the `Foo` it find is the last.

A lazy quantifier `.*?` will check for each characters if `Foo` follows.

Note: you can uncheck the `i` and `g` checkboxes in gskinner.